# How do you monitor your Ruby programming productivity?

Tags: ruby, monitoring

Ruby coders: How do you monitor your productivity?

I'm curious to know what you use to keep track of how much you do and how well you do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with an language, you must set goals/milestones for your project.  You then break those goals down into individuals tasks.  The smaller and more specific a task is, the easier it will be to track your progress.  I use a project management web application called [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine) to keep track of these tasks.  After I have devised the tests, I begin creating the code tests that will outline the code criteria for each test.  My primary use of Ruby has been with Ruby on Rails which has excellent support for testing.  Once I am done with the tests, I begin coding the application.  When the application passes all the tests for a given task, it can be marked as completed.

Answer (score 4):

For any programming task, the best way to track productivity is by tracking requirements/features delivered.  Every agile methodology puts emphasis on delivering working software [read meeting part of the requirements each sprint].  So indicators such as number of lines etc. is moot [when you have a person pair programming most of the time and checking in code with the other person's login].

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of a project, you can judge by the relevancy and number of tests.  Afterward, the number of passing tests.

*Relevancy* is the key word, of course.  If the code doesn't *do* anything yet, or doesn't deliver any value, then getting it to that point is your number one test of productivity.